# Can you set custom fields for a [Feature] Layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there some way I can "tag" a [Feature] Layer so that I can grab the layer from the service and see in some attribute LocationField =

I suppose I could put that information in the description and just parse it out, but I'm looking for a way to see what layers (if any) map to some "object" in my SQL database. I would much rather not have to put that kind of config info in my DB.